# How does Hibernate differenciate detached object from transient, where I set the id manually

Tags: java, hibernate

How does Hibernate differenciate detached object from transient object, where I set the id manually?
I mean, without consulting the database. For example, when I try to persist a transient object where I set the id manually, how will Hibernate know that my object is transient? or my object will be considered a detached object because the id is not empty?

Answer (score 3):

> Transient - an object is transient if it has just been instantiated
>   using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate
>   Session. It has no persistent representation in the database and no
>   identifier value has been assigned.
>
> Detached - a detached instance is an object that has been persistent,
>   but its Session has been closed. The reference to the object is still
>   valid, of course, and the detached instance might even be modified in
>   this state.

Hibernate api has class ClassMetadata with method getIdentifier , with this you can check stage for your entity.

```
SessionFactory sb f = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
ClassMetadata metadata = sf.getClassMetadata(data.getClass());

if(metadata.getIdentifier(data) == null) {
     return TRANSIENT;
}
```